# clang-tidy parsing error at spaceship operator

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, clang-tidy

Using `clang++-11` with `libstdc++-11` and `clang-tidy-11`, I run into failures when linting the code with `clang-tidy` - namely parsing error when dealing with the well-known sleeper `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));`.

```
clang-tidy-11 -header-filter=include/ -p=/tmp/dev/build/bin/aggregation/ -quiet /tmp/de
v/build/aggregation/src/main.cc
PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
0.      Program arguments: clang-tidy-11 -header-filter=include/ -p=/tmp/dev/build/bin/
aggregation/ -quiet /tmp/dev/build/aggregation/src/main.cc
1.      <eof> parser at end of file
2.      While analyzing stack:
        #0 Calling std::chrono::operator<=> at line /usr/include/c++/11/thread:125:6
        #1 Calling std::this_thread::sleep_for at line 159
        #2 Calling main
3.      /usr/include/c++/11/chrono:771:9: Error evaluating statement
4.      /usr/include/c++/11/chrono:771:9: Error evaluating statement
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-11.so.1(_ZN4llvm3sys15PrintStackTraceERNS_11raw_ostre
amE+0x1f)[0x7f4ae7718e7f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-11.so.1(_ZN4llvm3sys17RunSignalHandlersEv+0x50)[0x7f4
ae77171e0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-11.so.1(+0xbd1355)[0x7f4ae7719355]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x14140)[0x7f4aee8ec140]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-cpp.so.11(_ZN5clang4ento17BasicValueFactory25getPers
istentSValWithDataERKNS0_4SValEm+0x58)[0x7f4aedd82e38]
```

I checked it works fine with a [basic spaceship operator usage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/simplify-your-code-with-rocket-science-c20s-spaceship-operator/)

```
#include <compare>
struct IntWrapper {
  int value;
  constexpr IntWrapper(int value): value{value} { }
  auto operator<=>(const IntWrapper&) const = default;
};

constexpr bool is_lt(const IntWrapper& a, const IntWrapper& b) {
  return a < b;
}
int main() {
  static_assert(is_lt(0, 1));
}
```

The fiasco seems to occur at the last line of this template from `<chrono>`

```
    template<typename _Rep1, typename _Period1,
         typename _Rep2, typename _Period2>
      requires three_way_comparable<common_type_t<_Rep1, _Rep2>>
      constexpr auto
      operator<=>(const duration<_Rep1, _Period1>& __lhs,
          const duration<_Rep2, _Period2>& __rhs)
      {
    using __ct = common_type_t<duration<_Rep1, _Period1>,
                   duration<_Rep2, _Period2>>;
    return __ct(__lhs).count() <=> __ct(__rhs).count();
      }
```

I managed to get over this with a *temporary workaround* (suure) of using `boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));` as it's a dependency in my project anyway.

Do you have any *pointers*? Have I failed somewhere or perhaps it's well-known bug in clang-tidy and I should not hesitate to file a bug report?

Comment: Clear clang-tidy bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [std::this_thread::sleep_until](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) method with (now() + 1s) as argument.

Comment: It passes clang-tidy checks fine, without crashing it. A fine workaround indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed clang-tidy bug, https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47511 . I'll leave the question as it is, perhaps someone will find the `boost` trick useful until it's fixed.

Comment: This is resolved in clang-tidy-13 if anyone else is looking for an up to date solution